# Keyerror when using Json in python

Tags: python, json

I'm using a basic script to retrieve some trading data from an exchange, here is the response:

```
{'info': {'symbol': 'ETHBTC',
  'orderListId': -1,
  'price': '0.01083700',
  'origQty': '0.01800000',
  'executedQty': '0.00000000',
  'cummulativeQuoteQty': '0.00000000',
  'status': 'NEW',
  'timeInForce': 'GTC',
  'type': 'LIMIT',
  'side': 'BUY',
  'stopPrice': '0.00000000',
  'icebergQty': '0.00000000',
  'time': 1567078061338,
  'updateTime': 1567078061338,
  'isWorking': True}}
```

Now i want to print some parts of this response individually.

If i try:

```
tot = exchange.fetch_open_orders()
    for x in tot:
        print(x['symbol'])
```

I'll get: `'ETHBTC'`. Until now, everything is normal.

But if i try:

```
tot = exchange.fetch_open_orders()
    for x in tot:
        print(x['origQty'])
```

I get a `KeyError: 'origQty'`, which is weird, because this error should appear when i try to reference a parameter which doesn't exist, but it exists, since it is in my response. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: can you post the full script ? I tried with this json. I was able to get that origQty.

Comment: You'll need to show more of your code. What is `tot`? It can't be that dict you show, because iterating through a dict gives you just the keys.

Comment: What is `tot`? If it is the response dictionary then I would expect the first example to fail too

Comment: I'm sorry everyone. I just udated my question, now you can see where tot comes from

Answer (score 1):

Here you iterating dictionary on keys, so each time you are trying to get value from key, that's why it is giving `KeyError`.
This occurs when a key which is not present in a dictionary and still it accessed.
This can be achieved by following way.

```py
for x in tot:
    print(tot[x].get('symbol'))
    print(tot[x].get('origQty'))
```

Give output

```
ETHBTC
0.01800000
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is the format of `tot`. But you can try this.

```
for x, v in dict(tot).items():
    print(v['symbol'])
    print(v['origQty'])
```

Output:

```
ETHBTC
0.01800000
```